# Terraform installation of helm chart

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, dynatrace

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "app_dynatrace_namespace" {
  count = var.application_cluster_dynatrace ? 1 : 0
#  provider = kubernetes
   metadata {
    name = var.splitter_dynatrace_namespace
  }

  depends_on = [null_resource.cluster_creation]
}


resource "helm_release" "application_cluster_dynatrace" {
  count = var.application_cluster_dynatrace ? 1 : 0
 # provider = helm
  repository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dynatrace/helm-charts/master/repos/stable/"
  chart = "dynatrace-oneagent-operator"
  name = "dynatrace-oneagent-operator"
  namespace = var.app_dynatrace_namespace

  values = [
   var.application_cluster_dynatrace ? "${file("dev/dynatrace/dynatrace.yaml")}" : null
  ]

  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.app_dynatrace_namespace]
}
```

Variables file has below content:

```
 variable "application_cluster_dynatrace" {}
    variable "app_dynatrace_namespace" { default = "devns" }
```

I am using the above terraform script to create a namespace within a kubernetes cluster and then install the helm chart for dynatrace agent. When I run the script and mention "0" or false during the run time then terraform destroys the namespace and the dynatrace configuration. Is there a way in terraform to not destroy the namespace (ignore the steps) when a "0" or false is passed at run time ?

Terraform v0.12.26

- provider.google v3.24.0
- provider.google-beta v3.33.0
- provider.helm v1.2.2
- provider.kubernetes v1.11.3
- provider.null v2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

first of all, this is the expected behavior of terraform - if you changed count from 1 to 0, for terraform this means "0 resources should be deployed" and terraform delete it.

I think you can use different variables for "count" parameters. As for example, for app_dynatrace_namespace you can set "application_cluster_dynatrace_namespace" and for application_cluster_dynatrace leave the application_cluster_dynatrace.